# JSON undefined in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, internet-explorer-7

I am using the following line of JQuery code:

```
$.get('/ajax/buy', {'categoryname':chosenSelected}, function(data) {
   data = JSON.parse(data);
...
```

However, when running it on IE7 I get this error message: `JSON undefined:`.

How can I use the parser with compatibility to IE7 (and all major browsers)?

Answer (score 12):

You can use [parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) available in jQuery.

Comment: I'd comment that although the other answers are correct in that you can get getJSON or the other ajax functions, it is occasionally useful to be able to have an IE7-friendly alternative to JSON, so thanks for pointing this function out.

Comment: From jQuery source:

**parseJSON: JSON.parse,**

so I would not rely on jQuery.parseJSON.

Comment: for the record, about @Sam's comment. That is only true for jQuery 2.0, which has dropped support for older browsers. In 1.9.x, parseJSON is implemented with a fallback.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to parse JSON manually. You could use the [getJSON](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax/jQuery.getJSON) function:

```
$.getJSON('/ajax/buy', { 'categoryname' : chosenSelected }, function(data) {

    // data will be already a parsed JSON object
});
```

The `parse` method you are trying to call is available in the [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) library.

Comment: Thanks!
I can't find a similar $.postJSON function.
Any special reason for that?

Comment: And if there really isnt any function like, it seems like Luc'as idea will be good:

$.post('/ajax/buy', { 'categoryname' : chosenSelected }, function(data) {
data = jQuery.parseJSON(data);

Comment: No, please nothing on earth will convince me that it's better to parse the JSON manually rather than using the built-in functionality in jQuery, I mean this makes you write more code and the more code you have to achieve the same thing the more chance you have to get it wrong.

Comment: If you want to use `post` then why not: `$.post('/ajax/buy', { 'categoryname' : chosenSelected }, function(data) { // data will already be parsed here });`

Comment: Why will the data be parsed already?
"data" is a JSON created by "/ajax/buy"..
I need to parse it somehow.

Comment: Because when jQuery performs an AJAX call and the server sends the correct `Content-Type` header it will automatically parse the data.

Comment: In that case, then why should get be different than post? Why is there a special getJSON function?

Comment: In this case it is not different. `$.get` will also automatically parse. The reason to have `getJSON` is to explicitly specify that this server method will only return JSON and never XML or HTML for example, while `$.get` can handle all cases.

Answer (score 1):

You need add a JSON parser. The old browsers dont include that.

1 - Go to repository: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/

2 - Download and include json2.js in your site or app.

That is all.

Comment: As noted above, I believe its only strictly necessary when you also want to encode JavaScript to JSON.